# I'll be singing or I'll sing or I'm singing

Tags: tense, expressions, infinitive-vs-gerund

When you announce the name of the song you are going to sing right now, which expression is correct or most appropriate,; "Now, I'll be singing XXX." "Now, I'll sing XXX." or "Now, I'm singing XXX."?

The expected situation is where you give some words of congratulations in front of people and after finishing the speech, you're going to sing a song.

Comment: What is your context? If you're singing many songs, you can just say **"This next one is..."** or something similar. If you've been reading poetry or giving a safety briefing, and singing is a change from previous activity, I would use **"Now I'm going to sing..."** as an announcement of the change in format.

Comment: All are appropriate. But **context is key**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your intention is to announce the song that you will sing immediately following the announcement.

The choices you've offered for the announcement are:

1. Now, I'll be singing XXX.
2. Now, I'll sing XXX.
3. Now, I'm singing XXX.

The first two expressions are fine. "I'll" means "I will" or "I shall", which indicates a future action.

> **I'll** *contraction*
>   I shall; I will
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/i'll)

"Now" has just enough latitude in its semantic range to mean *next* in your context:

> **Now** *adverb*
>   1.1 At the time directly following the present moment; immediately.
>   ‘if we leave now we can be home by ten’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/now)

The third statement would be fine if instead of simply *speaking* that statement, you *sang* it. Otherwise, it doesn't sound as fluent as the other two choices.